# Riddle: What halacha is learned from something said by Satan?

Tags: riddle

Riddle: Name a halacha derived from a statement of Satan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement is [Job 2:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2702.htm)

> וַיַּעַן הַשָּׂטָן אֶת יְהוָה, וַיֹּאמַר:  עוֹר בְּעַד עוֹר, וְכֹל אֲשֶׁר לָאִישׁ--יִתֵּן, בְּעַד נַפְשׁוֹ
>
> And the Satan said to God: skin on behalf of skin, and all a man has, he will give for his own life.

The Halacha is that while we may not redeem a captive if the price is too high, an individual is entitled to spend as much of his own money as he likes on redeeming *himself* (and possibly his spouse).  This is based on the above verse.
  --Tosfos, Kesubos 52a, s.v. והיו.

My understanding of Tosfos is that the verse is describing a reality of human behavior.  Since:

- Any normal person would do anything to save themselves

AND

- [Rabbinic enactments can only be made if most people are likely to abide by them](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/e302.htm).

THEREFORE:

- The rabbis excepted one's self from the "no exorbitant ransom" rule

Comment: How does this apply to the cases in Israel today? What price is considered "too high" to get soldiers back? If their lives are at risk, is that considered a case of pidyon shvuim, or pikuach nefesh?

Comment: Ashkenazi Chief Rabbi Yona Metzger observed that 30-40% of the people Israel releases (in exchange for its own) will go do more terrorist stuff, and that released terrorists have so far killed 50+ Israelis.  On the other hand, he pointed out that the "we get our boys back no matter what" policy is a morale-booster for the troops, and enables them to do maneuvers that they otherwise couldn't.  This generalized pikuach nefesh is a consideration they can (and do) weigh against the Mishnaic enactment.