# TIKKUN OLAM תיקון עולם

Tags: history, repentance-teshuvah, rosh-hashanah-new-year, olam-haba-world-to-come, tikkunim

I am looking for material about TIKKUN OLAM, POST TALMUDIC PERIOD, NOT kabbalist (too difficult for my students) somebody can give share a few links or detailed resources?

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3700275/jewish/What-Is-Tikkun-Olam.htm

Comment: see also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10366